# Javascript regex to detect emptiness or specific pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) for my form. I added an additional method to check for valid SSN values.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    'ssn',
    function(e,i,a) {
        return e.match(/^(\d{10})$/);
    },
    'SSN is not valid'
);
```

It works fine, but the problem is that the field is not required, and if the user does not input any data in the field, it still gets validated and throws an error.

This validation should only take place IF and ONLY IF the user actually inputs some data in that field. How can I cover that in the regex? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. By adding `?` it now expects an optional 10 digits.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    'ssn',
    function(e,i,a) {
        return e.match(/^(\d{10})?$/);
    },
    'SSN is not valid'
);
```